# How do I strip the symbol table in so?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I used the `strip` command under MAC to remove the symbol table.
And then I'm going to check it with the `strings` and `grep` command.
Then I found that even class private function names can be `grep`.

```
class ModuleBarn
{
public:
    /***/
    
private:
    void m_Link( FunctionSet* fs, const char* functionName );
    Field* m_FindField( Function* fun, uint32_t argIdx );
    Function* m_FindCall( const char* functionName, const char* moduleName );
}

alldeMac-mini:~ all$ strip libBootloader.so

alldeMac-mini:~ all$ strings libBootloader.so | grep m_Link
_ZN10ModuleBarn6m_LinkEPNS_11FunctionSetEPKc
```

How do I strip the public and private function names in a class?

Comment: Why you would want to do this? You can use `c++filt`  to demangle the names, then you can target the specific class methods you want. How you would strip them, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Because there’s `.so` in your output I assume you’re doing all that on Linux? If yes, you need to do 2 things.

1. Modify your build scripts/make files/cmake lists/whatever build environment you use adding following compiler switches: `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden` Very likely you’ll lose exported symbols, mark them individually in the source code with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`.
2. Use the `strip` binary that shipped with the OS.